# Is this the appropriate way to create a repeating background IntentService?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask, android-service

I had previously used an `AlarmManager` to run a task on a set time interval. However, my task requires `AsyncTask` and ran into some issues with the `AlarmManager` stopping before the task completes. I am now trying to use a `IntentService` instead, and was wondering if the below example code is the proper way to set up a repeating `Service`.

The task takes >10 seconds and downloads data in the background without the user having to do anything.

In my MainActivity.class:

```
//called when user sets some in settings
public void setAlarm() {
     //initialize alarm.setRepeating(...)
     //...
}
```

In my Alarm.class onReceive, extends BroadcastReceiver:

```
//runs when alarm reaches its set time interval
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     //startService(...)
}
```

In my AsyncService.class, extends IntentService:

```
//runs when alarm starts the service
public void onHandleIntent(Nullables, etc) {
     //run my AsyncTask
}
```

Comment: Consider using [JobIntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService) instead of IntentService, it handles correctly background execution limits for Android 8+

Comment: I wish I got your advice a few hours earlier, I spent an hour debugging with IntentService and just figured out to use JobIntentService after background permission errors. Thanks for the confirmation though!